# Modify property of non-null field using relection/annotations

Tags: java, reflection

I have this:

```
package general;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SetTable {
  String table();
}

class Star {
  public String foo = "";
  public String toString(){
    return "<Star> : " + this.foo;
  }
}

class Bar {

  @SetTable(table = "xxx")
  public Star s = new Star();
  public String toString(){
    return "<Bar> : " + this.s.toString();
  }
}

class AnnotationInjector {
  public static void inject(Object instance) {
    Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();


    for (Field field : fields) {

      if (field.isAnnotationPresent(SetTable.class)) {

        SetTable set = field.getAnnotation(SetTable.class);
        field.setAccessible(true); // should work on private fields

        try {
          field.set(instance, set.table());  // this is not what I need
          //  ***
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public class AnnotationTest {

  @Test
  public void first() {

    var b = new Bar();
    AnnotationInjector.inject(b);
    System.out.println(b.toString());
  }


}
```

right now the code is trying to set  new Bar().s to a String, but that won't work, because new Bar().s needs to be an instance Star. But that's not what I want to do anyway. What I want to do is access s and set this:

```
new Bar().s.foo = "whatever"
```

so on the line above designated by ***

I am looking to do something like:

```
((Star)field).foo = "whatever";
```

but that's not right. Is it possible to modify a field after it's been assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Counterintutively, the syntax to do this is:

```
  Star x = (Star)field.get(instance);
```

this line can modify the properties of the pre-existing `Star s` field on `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I suggest you add an `interface` with method for setting the value in order to make setting the value more general instead of checking on instances and their types, and make the `Star` class implements it, as the following:

```
interface ISetValue {
   void setValue(String value);
}

class Star implements ISetValue{

  public String foo = "";

  @Override
  public void setValue(String value) {
    foo = value; 
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "<Star> : " + this.foo;
  }
}
```

And your `AnnotationInjector` class should check if the field implements `ISetValue` and onvoke `setValue` method for it, should be something like the following:

```
class AnnotationInjector {
  public static void inject(Object instance) {
    Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();


    for (Field field : fields) {

      if (field.isAnnotationPresent(SetTable.class)) {

        SetTable set = field.getAnnotation(SetTable.class);
        field.setAccessible(true); // should work on private fields

        try {
          //field.set(instance, set.table());  // this is not what I need
          //  *** 
          //Change is here
           Class fieldType = field.getType();
           if(ISetValue.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType) ){
                Object fieldValue = field.get(instance);
                Method myMethod = fieldValue.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getDeclaredMethod("setValue", new Class[]{String.class});
                myMethod.invoke(fieldValue,set.table());
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now your output should be:

```
<Bar> : <Star> : xxx
```